# Can I allow use of a property while limiting exposure to liability?

Tags: canada, liability, real-property

I own a semi-rural property in Canada which I use as a seasonal residence; it's unoccupied for long periods. People in the surrounding community are accustomed to traversing the property recreationally: hiking, fishing, snowmobiling. I'm fine with this and other innocuous daytime use, but I want to limit my liability. I plan to post a sign prohibiting hunting, open fires, and trespass after dark.

I know of no truly hidden hazards--no old wells, for example--but there are a few ways to get hurt, especially in the winter: thin ice, obstacles buried under the snow, hard-to-see fence wires and posts. These are things common to such properties and, imo, generally known to people likely to be engaging in these activities. But that's what everyone says when someone is hurt on their property. And if someone broke into a shed or climbed on a roof, then there's lots of ways to get hurt.

Is there a way I can word a sign to allow people to pass, but limit my liability?